# Resolving referenced Assemblies for mixed-mode DLL in a plugin

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

So I have a managed BHO for Internet Explorer, that loads a native DLL, which depends on a mixed-mode DLL, that depends on another managed DLL.

So the dependencies are basically like this:

```
IE.BHO.dll (Managed DLL)
|-> IE.Hook.dll (Native DLL)
    |-> Core.Communication.CPP.dll (Mixed-Mode dll)
        |-> Core.Communication.dll (Managed DLL)
```

I have gotten as far as loading IE.Hook.dll, which instantiates a class in Core.Communication.CPP.dll. But as soon as Core.Communication.CPP.dll attempts to use code that is in Core.Communication.dll, I get a FileNotFoundException that says it cannot find the Core.Communication assembly.

They are all located in the same directory. Core.Communication.dll also has a dependency on protobuf-net, which is also located in the same directory.

What do I need to do to make sure that the managed DLL can be loaded by the mixed-mode DLL?

Update:

Fusion Log is showing this:

```
Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Core.Communication, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Internet Explorer/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Internet Explorer/Core.Communication.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Internet Explorer/Core.Communication/Core.Communication.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Internet Explorer/Core.Communication.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Internet Explorer/Core.Communication/Core.Communication.EXE.
```

So it seems to only be looking in the application directory, which I guess makes some sense. I assume there must be a way to get it to look in my installation directory, but I'm not sure how. Changing the current working directory doesn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: By mixed mode I assume you refer to a C++/CLI DLL, have you tried using Fusion Log (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx) to see if you can get the cause?

Comment: Yes, a C++/CLI DLL. I have not tried Fusion Log because I did not know it existed. I will give it a shot now, though. Thanks :)

Comment: So for some reason I'm not getting anything in the viewer, but I noticed a Fusion Log property in the exception object while debugging. Basically it seems like it's only looking for the DLL in the application directory, which is C:/Program Files (x86)/Internet Explorer/, instead of where all of my DLLs are located. Which I guess makes some sense. Just not sure how to get it to look in my directory. Setting the working directory doesn't make a difference.

Comment: This is entirely normal, the CLR looks in the GAC first, then the directory that contains the EXE.  The GAC is of course a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

So I found [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which seems to work for me. Not sure if this is the Best Way™ to do it or not, so I'm still open to other answers :)